# Pandas cumsum groupby between dates

Tags: python, pandas, date-range, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I am trying to get a cumulative sum, grouped by album, where my sales date is between two dates.

This works fine with no date range used:

```
df[‘cum_sales’] = df.groupby(by = ['album_name','song_name']) ['sales'].cumsum()
```

This is where its not working for me, When trying to start a new cum sum for only between the dates filtered:

```
df[‘filtered_sales'] = df.groupby(by = [‘album_name’,'song_name’]) ['sales']
[( df['sale_date'] >= df['static_date_col'] ) & 
 ( df['sale_date'] <= pd.datetime.now() ) ].cumsum()
```

> **Exception error**: Column(s) sales already selected.

Maybe I should be using a mask instead? At a loss and need some guidance.

Per Wen's suggestion I tried the following:

```
df[‘filtered_sales'] = df[‘sales’] 
[( df['sale_date'] >= ['static_date_col'] ) & 
( df['sale_date'] <= pd.datetime.now() ) ].groupby(by = 
[‘album_name’,'song_name’]).cumsum()
```

> **Key error**: 'album_name'

Comment: filter before `groupby`

Comment: I'm back to receiving the key exclusion error I was having prior to this problem:

Comment: `df.loc[( df['sale_date'] >= df['static_date_col'])&( df['sale_date'] <= pd.datetime.now()),:].groupby(by = ['album_name','song_name']).cumsum()`

Comment: Thank you Wen. That got me what I needed. Using .loc in that way never occurred to me. I learned something new.

Comment: YW ~  :-) Nice day